# Using asynchronous call when setting text D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some code similar to the following :

```js
nodeEnter.append('text')
  .text(async function(d) {
    var count = await dispatch('GetCount', {
      chosenNode: d
    });
    return count || 'N/A';
  });
```

When running this, the text that shows looks like this :

```
[object Promise]
```

The function works but obviously returns before the promise returns anything. How would I go about awaiting an action in code similar to the above ?

I am using Vuex with VueJs, that's what the dispatch is working with.

Comment: That‘s the expected behavior. An [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) returns a Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the function.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was expecting the count value to be returned from the action that's awaited. Obviously I'm doing it wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The d3 `.text()` method does not play well with async / await.

The promise object you see is because `async function()...` is returning a promise. Even if you just return a constant from an async decorated function, you still get a promise sent to the d3 `text()` method.

Here is the source of d3's `text()` method

```js
function textRemove() {
  this.textContent = "";
}

function textConstant(value) {
  return function() {
    this.textContent = value;
  };
}

function textFunction(value) {
  return function() {
    var v = value.apply(this, arguments);
    this.textContent = v == null ? "" : v;
  };
}

export default function(value) {
  return arguments.length
      ? this.each(value == null
          ? textRemove : (typeof value === "function"
          ? textFunction
          : textConstant)(value))
      : this.node().textContent;
}
```

Luckily, when a function is passed it is invoked with the `apply()` method which binds the d3 'this' context, so we can easily carry out the `textContent` assignment within the `.then()` callback of the promise, like so

```js
/* 
  Because the 'this' context changes below, need to grab 'dispatch' here
  This is specific to Vuex implementation mentioned in the question
  When using a different async function, just make sure it's within closure
*/
const dispatch = this.$store.dispatch  

nodeEnter.append('text')
  .text(function(d) {
    dispatch('GetCount', {
      chosenNode: d
    }).then(val => {
      this.textContent = val  // This is normally done in d3's text() method
    })

    /* 
      Don't return anything.
      d3's text() method will receive 'undefined'
      and not update textContent
    */
    // return count || 'N/A';
  });
```

Comment: brilliant, I didnt think of doing this, and helped me understand what I am actually setting (this.textContent), thanks